# SQL Server setting Default when creating table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am kinda new to SQL and after learning MySQL now im giving SQL Server a go.

I am creating a new table, in which i want the column employer_id to be automatically updated everytime i insert values to other columns.

I wrote the below and added it to 'Default Value or Binding' in SSMS:

```
CONCAT(334600,IF no_id>=10 SELECT no_id 
ELSE CONCAT(0,no_id),substring(last_name, 1, 1),substring(first_name, 1, 1))
```

Idea is that column id_no will automatically have a value based on `IDENTITY(1,1)`, and I can use that number with the first letter of the first_name and last_name to automatically generate a unique employer number.

The result is expected to be:

```
id_no | first_name | last_name | employer_id

1     | John       | Hamilton  | 33460001HJ
```

However this does not work!
it keeps saying:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Server [pc_name]\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you are trying to put more data into a column than the column size allows. But I don't think this is going to work for you anyway. What is the point of a static 3346000 as the beginning of each value? If anything I would make this a computed column but I still don't see how it is really very useful. What happens when somebody changes their name?

Comment: dear Sean, Thanks for the quick reply. i am just experiencing really, just wanna learn and i think the best way to learn is just to make complex stuff and try to resolve them. what is a computed column may i ask?

Comment: My point about the prefix is that we try to avoid duplicating data in a database when possible. And if every single row start with 334600 it is kind of silly to store in the database. Why store that prefix on a million rows? That is 6 million characters that provide no benefit at all. As for computed columns, see the answer below.

Comment: well you are right. i am just creating a database to try to learn tsql really. i really did not want to generate a unique way of coding each individual entry, just as a practice to get to know things better. but yeh, thanks i will keep your advice in mind.

Comment: If FORMAT is supported by your version : `UPPER(CONCAT(334600, FORMAT(no_id,'00'), left(first_name,1), left(last_name,1)))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a default value. Those are only used if you insert a null into that column, not after an update. If you want a column to be updated every time you change something in another column, you need a computed column. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

```
alter table myTable
add myComputedColumn AS CONCAT(
    334600,
    right('0' + cast(no_id as varchar), 2),    -- this is a better way to add leading zeros
    substring(last_name, 1, 1),
    substring(first_name, 1, 1)
);
```

If you want the data to be physically stored in the table, you can use a persisted computed column.

Comment: how can i do this using SMSS?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio? Connect to your database, create a new query and modify the code above to match your table and column names (or I am not sure what you mean). If you want to do it with the designer (Which I find harder because you have to be more accurate with brackets), you want the property "Computed column specification", near where you found "default value or binding".

Comment: many thanks Peter for your kind help. so if i paste 'CONCAT(334600,right('0' +cast(no_id as varchar), 2),substring(last_name, 1, 1),substring(first_name, 1, 1)); into the (Formula) place will it work?

Comment: Yes, without the `;` it should. You might have to tweak the formula a bit but that's the general idea.